# Как поменять (вычислить) базовый background-color данной строки/ячейки в гриде в зависимости от параметров?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

У меня есть грид и там заданы базовые расцветки фона ячеек для четных и нечетных строк (бледно-желтый и почти белый). Мне нужно изменять цвет в зависимости от разных параметров. Например заблокирован (цвет выставить в светло-серый, немного отличающийся для четной и нечетной строк), или выставлено значение одного из полей равное некоему значению и т.п.

Самый простой способ - завести список переменных с цветами для всех возможных случаев. Но если я хочу создать разные темы, то это выглядит неэффективно.

Есть ли возможность накладывать некие фильтры или по каким-то формулам вычислять цвет - например, если есть признак заблокированности, то сдвинуть цвет на %%. Или еще как-то...

Я пробовал смотреть css фильтры (backdrop-filter), потратил почти день, но толку мало.

Возможно кто-то такое уже делал. Или возможно это вообще нужно по-другому делать. Подскажите, пожалуйста. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

как раз у себя нечто подобное изобретаю, самое путное из того что вышло - `animation: both -*s paused`

для удобства в добавлении\убавлении: яркости, цветности и выбора оттенка удобнее всего использовать `hsl` палитру.

```css
#a{display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr)}
:root{--s: 50%; --l: 50%;}
/* исходные цветность(~насыщенность) и светлота(~яркость) */

#a li:nth-child(even){--l: 30%;} /*четные затемняем*/
#a li.lock{--s: 0%;} /*локи обесцвечиваем*/

@keyframes list{ /*а это считай скины*/
0%{background: hsl(100, var(--s), var(--l))}
1%{background: hsl(200, var(--s), var(--l))}
2%{background: hsl(300, var(--s), var(--l))}
100%{background: hsl(360, var(--s), var(--l))}
}

#a li{animation: list 100s linear both paused;}
/*при 'both paused', 'animation-delay' выбирает и фиксирует кадр = выбор скина*/
#w>li{animation-delay: -0s;}
#x>li{animation-delay: -1s;}
#y>li{animation-delay: -2s;}
#z>li{animation-delay: -50s;}
#a li:after{content: attr(class)}
```

```html
<div id='a'>
<ol id='w'>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class='lock'></li>
  <li class='lock'></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
<ol id='x'>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class='lock'></li>
  <li class='lock'></li>
  <li></li>
</ol><ol id='y'>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class='lock'></li>
  <li class='lock'></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
<ol id='z'>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class='lock'></li>
  <li class='lock'></li>
  <li></li>
</ol></div>
```

и да, вместо тонны переменных с цветами, получим треть тонны `delay'ев` или даже целых анимаций...

```
#w>li{animation-delay: -0s;}
#x>li{animation-delay: -1s;}
#y>li{animation-delay: -2s;}
#z>li{animation-delay: -50s;}
```

наиболее приятное отличие от возни с перечислением всех переменных - теперь нет сотни этих гхм... "переменных" в вообще каждом теге(при просмотре через инспектор), только одна анимация и та пара переменных на основе которых она "собрана".

почти как функция в полноценном ЯП, или даже конструктор :3

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно, что вы вкладываете в значение слова "заблокирован". как это отмечаеться в html ? Самым простым способом будет присваивание заблокированому элементу класса, который визуально будет переопределять его цвет. Вам в зависимости от параметров которые будут записанны в таблицу/грид необходимо добавлять необходимые классы.

```css
table{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
    height: auto;
}
table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid #595959;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 35px;
}
table th {
    background: #347c99; 
    color: #fff; 
}

table td:nth-of-type(even){
  background-color: #ff0;
}

table td.close{
  background-color: #777;
}
```

```html
<table class="iksweb">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>two</td>
            <td>tree</td>
            <td>four</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>six</td>
            <td class="close">seven</td>
            <td>eight</td>
            <td>nine</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: заблокирован - это про данные, т.е. с бэка пришел массив строк для таблицы и там в специальном поле например выставлен флаг блокировки строки, что бы ее нельзя было редактировать

Comment: Да, это способ тоже мне в голову пришел в первую очередь, но если нужно будет поддерживать множество тем, то как-то это все не очень эффективно выглядит. Может я и ошибаюсь.

Comment: Не понятна ваша структура данных. Приведите ваш html/css .   Если там в ячейках атрибуты `disabled` добавляються, то отталкивайтесь от этого.  *:disabled {
  background-color: dimgrey;
  color: linen;
}

Comment: цвета можно передавать, не только в HEX формате, но и в многих других... к примеру https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/css/color-formats

Comment: Я наверно неясно задал вопрос - вопрос не в том чтобы как понять какую ячейку/строку подкрашивать серым, как заблокированную, а в том можно ли как-то не просто применять другой background-color, а как бы изменять уже назначенный цвет - может быть фильтры добавлять...

Или как вариант, предположим у меня есть css-переменная с базовым цветом, а для заблокированных я на основе этого базового вычисляю значение переменной с цветом для заблокированных.

Comment: Т.е. чтобы не было такого что я тупо руками набираю сотню значений, а чтобы они могли сами заранее или налету в зависимости от атрибута или класса рассчитаться или измениться...

Чтобы не нужно было делать эту обезьянью работу с ручным набором значений цветов

Comment: Оно и так будет изменяться в зависимости от вашего значения если там есть указаный параметр или атребут на которое поцеплено это изменение... почитайте как работает CSS.  Даже если вы в риалтайме будете дергать значения с фондовой биржи то оно будет менять css параметры если там есть к чему привязаться.